What is the translation of misgendering in French?
Misgendering is:

the act of using the incorrect gender when referring to another person.

Example:

A United Airlines passenger flying from San Francisco to Austin with her young child was kicked off her flight on Wednesday after misgendering a flight attendant. It’s disputed whether the misgendering incident is the only reason for her removal.

What is the translation of misgendering in French?

Google Translate proposes "Misgenre" but I don't see any use of it on Google search.
https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Misgender: no results.
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english-french?q=Misgender: no results.
https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/misgender: no results.


Presumably the French word for "the act of using the incorrect gender when referring to another person" has a gender, French being the sort of language that it is;-)

WordReference has three translations at misgender (English to French). I would post this as an answer but I don't have any original content to add.

The verb mégenrer (OQLF), built exactly like misgender, and the associated noun mégenrage (OQLF) have been around for a few years but are still little known albeit on the rise as the comments show.

Le verbe mégenrer (OQLF), construit exactement comme misgender, et le nom associé mégenrage (OQLF) existent depuis quelques années. Ils sont encore très peu connus mais leur usage progresse comme le montrent les commentaires.

Mégenrer appeared in the 2024 edition of the Petit Robert:

La question du genre est de plus en plus prégnante en France, et son champ lexical se développe. Le mot "mégenrer" est apparu, désignant le fait d'attribuer à une personne, volontairement ou non, un genre dans lequel la personne ne se reconnaît pas. "Le genre est un thème créateur de mots nouveaux", explique Géraldine Moinard, la directrice éditoriale du Petit Robert. "Le mot 'iel' était entré il y a deux ans. Cela a été une surprise pour nous de voir un débat aussi virulent pour un mot de trois lettres", se souvient-elle.

RadioFrance.fr May 2023.

Mégenrer et mégenrage sont les termes recommandés par l’Office québécois de la langue française (OQLF).

mégenrer est effectivement le terme que j'ai le plus entendu employé pour décrire cette situation (France métropolitaine). En tout cas dans des sphères LGBT ou LGBT-informées, ce mot est connu, compris et usité

Utilisé et compris sans soucis dans les sphères militantes de France hexagonale. À utiliser et à démocratiser maintenant.

Note that le Larousse is a right-wing leaning dictionary who tend to be quite late on this kind of progressive subject.
Wikitionnaire thanks to its contribute logic is the most up-to-date but it is often not seen as an official source, still it has mégenrer:

Étymologie
(XXIe siècle) Du préfixe mé- et du nom commun genre.
Verbe
mégenrer \me.ʒɑ̃.ʁe\ transitif direct 1er groupe (voir la conjugaison)

(Transitude) (Emploi transitif et parfois absolu) Attribuer à une personne, volontairement ou non, un genre dans lequel la personne ne se reconnaît pas[1].

La plupart des cissexuel·les sont inconscient·es de la nature subjective du genrement, essentiellement car elleux-mêmes ne vivent pas l’expérience d’être régulièrement mégenrées – i.e. assigné·es par erreur à un genre qui ne leur correspond pas. — (Julia Serano, « Démanteler le privilège cissexuel », dans Manifeste d’une femme trans, traduit de l’anglais par Noémie Grunenwald, Tahin Party, 2007, page 54.)
Sachez que même si vous nous mégenrez involontairement, l’impact est présent. L’équation est simple : un mégenrage = une micro-agression. — (UESG, « Mégenrer c’est violent » sur le blogue Unique en son genre : Le blog trans-lucide, 1er janvier 2016.)
Je passe mon temps à me demander si je dois reprendre les gens ou laisser courir quand ils me mégenrent et en même temps je sais à quoi je ressemble. Ça me saoule, ça me rappelle la binarité malsaine de cette société, […]. — (Mark, « J’ai 30 ans, je mue et je flotte : je suis adolescent », sur le site Female2male, 2 septembre 2015.)
Les personnes qui te genrent correctement après une journée entière à être mégenréx c’est vraiment les bests de la vie (et ça sauve accessoirement, genrez correctement les gens) — (Aztruc. twitter. 2021 → lire en ligne)
Mégenrer peut se traduire par l'utilisation de pronoms, d'un vocabulaire, d'accords ou de salutations qui ne correspondent pas à l'identité de genre de la personne dont il est question. — (Bureau de la traduction, Lexique sur la diversité sexuelle et de genre sur Gouvernement du Canada, février 2019)



Traductions

Anglais : misgender (en)
Suédois : felköna (sv)

Références

Le Grand Robert de la langue française, Le Robert, 2005-2008 (version de démonstration)

Sources

↑ Bureau de la traduction, Lexique sur la diversité sexuelle et de genre sur Gouvernement du Canada, février 2019.


Récupérée de « https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=mégenrer&oldid=34829072 »

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9genrer
A good middle between Larousse and Wikitionnaire is leRobert, who is both seen as serious and is faster than larousse has mégenrer too:

Définition de mégenrer ​​​ verbe transitif
didactique Attribuer à (qqn) un genre qui ne correspond pas à son identité de genre. Mégenrer une personne trans.

https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/megenrer
LeRobert also have a conjugaison table: https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/conjugaison/megenrer

J'ai découvert "mégenrer" dans la réponse de @jlliagre.
J'aurais simplement traduit "misgendering" par erreur volontaire/délibérée sur le genre.

Mégenrer est dans le Robert https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54762/3785
